# Tweepy / Twitter API V2 can make tweets but get 401 when searching

Tags: tweepy, twitter-api-v2

I am on a developer account where for the last year I have been developing a bot.  Originally I used v1.1 to make tweets and now with v2 I have updated my code to make tweets successfully.

Now I am try to do searches using `search_recent_tweets`.  The full search I have read is restricted to Academic access which I don't have for my bot.  But I should be able to get `search_recent_tweets` to return results?

When I use `client.search_recent_tweets` from python code with tweepy, I get a 401 Unauthorized Error and I wonder why since my credentials work for making tweets.  My search code is:

```
from config_v2 import create_client

# Create Client object
client = create_client()

query = 'point_radius:[25.11 -82.054 1km]'
dict_object = client.search_recent_tweets(query=query, max_results = 10, start_time='2022-12-06T05:00:00Z')

with open('geo_test.txt', 'w') as f:
    for k in dict_object.keys():
        f.write(k + '\t' + dict_object[k] + '\n')
```

My authentication code:

```
client = tweepy.Client(
    consumer_key=CONSUMER_KEY,
    consumer_secret=CONSUMER_SECRET,
    access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN,
    access_token_secret=ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET
)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two separate problems with the above code:

First to get past the 401 Error, we can add the `BEARER TOKEN` as well into the instantiation of the `Client`.  This will allow basic search operations to take place.

Second, in my case I would get a `400 Bad Request` message upon doing the above.  There is so much conflicting information on the web, but it appears the point_radius is an Enterprise filter (meaning it costs money and is not automatically included to a developer) and as I am not an Enterprise user, it is not available to me.  But, the basic query like `@twitterapi` will work for whatever that is worth.  Too bad, because I was especially interested in the Geo capabilities of the Twitter API and that was the whole point of using it.